# rsync and original permissions

Tags: debian, permissions, rsync, usb-device

I know that there are a lot of treads about this subject, but I was unable to solve it.

I'd like to make a simple backup with `rsync` between my hard drive and a USB device. My original directories and files have different permissions (0664, 0644, 0444, 0755, etc.).

I tried various option, the basic one is

```
rsync -avzu --delete --delete-after --progress /source /target
```

(and -a implies -p, which «preserve permissions», as says the linux man page). But in the USB device I find all permissions set to 0777, independently of issuing the command as simple user or as root.

The device is mounted in `/media` (I'm working on a Debian machine) and its permissions are automatically set to 0777. So, I have the impression that `rsync` is limited to giving the device permissions to files and directories, instead of keeping the original ones.

Is there a way to solve with `rsync`, or have I to change permissions at a later time with `chmod`?

Comment: What filesystem is your usb stick? How is it mounted and what are parameters?

Comment: If the filesystem on the USB drive does not support Unix permissions (and/or ownership etc.), then this meta-data can not be preserved.

Comment: computer filesystem is ext4. USB stick filesystem is NTFS; it's mounted automatically: where can I desume the options? Or simply NTFS doesn't support linux permission? I'm from many years a Linux user, so I'm not so aware of Windows permissions...

Answer (score 0):

You may not be using ACLs on your ext4 (source) filesystem.  NTFS is going to want ACLs only.  `rsync` is not going to translate a POSIX style (ugo) permission to an ACL.

If you do have existing ACLs on your ext4, you can try to transfer them with -A or --acls.

Comment: `root@darkstar:~# tune2fs -l /dev/sdc4 | grep "Default mount options"
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl`. I tried: `rsync -avzuA --delete --delete-after --progress /source /target`. but the permissions are not the original ones: still changed in  0777. Or is there anything wrong in the options I pass to rsync?

Comment: All `rsync` is doing is trying to recreate via a `chmod()` call.  What happens if you try it yourself and do `chmod 0644 /target/file`?   If the filesystem doesn't honor that call, then the information is discarded.

Comment: I tried with chmod regardless of rsync, and nothig happens. Is there a way to solve with or without rsync? Have I to do anything on USB stick filesystem?

Comment: Your choices might be: use something other than `rsync` to encode the perms in another way (like `tar`), or use another filesystem on the USB (NTFS is okay for interoperability, but ext would hold the permissions properly).  I don't know of anything like rsync, but which encodes the permissions in a hidden file or similar.   Tar keeps the perms, but makes it harder to do incremental updates.

Comment: I need a NTFS system for interoperability. In the school where I teach almost all computers use Windows, so I couldn't read a ext filesystem. I'll try tar. Thank you!